# Unable to import BeautifulSoup(pylint import error)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to build a web scraper in Python (with permission). I have bs4 installed and requests installed, as well as pylint, yet I can't import either of them to my .py file. When I save my file, I get problems in VSCode like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WcNe.png). I've tried looking at other StackOverflow questions but nothing seems to address this problem. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment by any chance? In that case, the python environment in VSCode might be different from the one where you installed bs4. I'd suggest you to check the python environment that VSCode is pointing at

Comment: I never started up a virtual environment. I'm new to Python and VSCode, how can I check environment it's pointing at and if it's pointing to the wrong place, am I able to just move files to correct it?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments This might help you to set up Python in VSCode. Anyway, are you able to run your python script in a terminal saying ```python filename.py``` ? If so, then its is just a VSCode issue that you can fix using this link

Answer (score 0):

To import beautiful soup, use

`pip install beautifulsoup4`

To import it into your project

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`